# Wait for next parts while extracting .rar archives

Tags: archive, rar

is there any possibility to extract rar archives consisting of many parts that are not completely downloaded yet? As I remember, WinRAR supports this function since it asks you for the path of the next part as soon as it has reached the end of parts, and somehow it detects when the next file has appeared. Not sure if a WinRAR extension was needed though.

Anyway, I haven't found any possibility to do that with tools that run natively on Ubuntu, and I would be very happy if someone knows any.